# Why is my form only passing input data from last field within foreach loop to database?

Tags: php, mysql, html, laravel

I am trying to update some data in my database from a form with this foreach loop:

```
$players_ids = $_POST['player_ids'];

    foreach($players_ids as $player_id) {

        foreach($_POST['goals'] as $goals) {

            var_dump($goals);
            $updateGoals = \DB::table('stats')->where('id', $player_id)->update(['goals' => $goals]);
        }

        foreach($_POST['assists'] as $assists) {

            var_dump($assists);
            $updateAssists = \DB::table('stats')->where('id', $player_id)->update(['assists' => $assists]);
        }

        foreach($_POST['tackles'] as $tackles) {

            var_dump($tackles);
            $updateTackles = \DB::table('stats')->where('id', $player_id)->update(['tackles' => $tackles]);
        }

    }
```

Here is the form:

```
@foreach($players as $player)    

<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="player_ids[]" value="{{ $player->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="game_id" value="{{ $game->id }}">
    <td>{{ $player->fn }} {{ $player->ln }}</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="0" name="goals[]" placeholder="goals"></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="0" name="assists[]" placeholder="assists"></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="0" name="tackles[]" placeholder="tackles"></td>
</tr>

@endforeach
```

When I try to submit this data, instead of passing through the individual stats of each player to the database, it only passes through the data of the last player in the foreach loop to every player. So if the final player has 3 goals, everyone will get 3 goals in the database. This is obviously not how I would like this to function.

I know soon after this I will run into an issue with updating the data in my database, because I'm not looking to override what is already in the database, but instead add the value passed through to the value already in the database, so if anyone has any knowledge on that as well would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your form has multiple copies of elements with the *same* name. Due to this, it only uses the last element with that name.

To utilize an array of values, you will need to use `[]` like you did for `player_ids`.

Comment: Okay, I have updated the question to reflect that and what I thought I would need to change, but it is still not working. I have run a var_dump() on each of the variables to make sure it is receiving the correct value for each one, and it is, but it's still only entering the data of the last player into the database for everyone. The var_dump() also reveals it is passing through three instances of each stat set like so:

Comment: `string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "3" string(1) "3" string(1) "2" string(1) "1" string(2) "34" string(2) "35" string(2) "33" string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "3" string(1) "3" string(1) "2" string(1) "1" string(2) "34" string(2) "35" string(2) "33" string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "3" string(1) "3" string(1) "2" string(1) "1" string(2) "34" string(2) "35" string(2) "33"`

Comment: For each instance, the index of the array is what groups them together. For something as complex as this, you may want to use AJAX to submit the form and instead build an array of JSON objects to send through -- it will be easier to manage on the server side.

Comment: So I put this issue off for a while while addresing other aspects of the application I am building, but have run out of problems and am back to this and need to find a solution. How would I go about doing this? I can now successfully create a gamelog, but how would I add the values from the `gamelog` to the `stats` table. Do I need to first retrieve the values from the `stats` table in order to add the values passed through from the gamelog, or can I simply "update" the table based on these values from an array indexed with each `player_id`?

Comment: Real sorry, am on my phone at school and thought this was the question where I explained what each of those models/tables were. How would I go about using JSON to build an array which I could then add to the values that already exist in the database?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is you are updating each player with the very last value set for goals, assists, and tackles.  (Actually you are updating each player with every set for goals, assists and tackles, resulting in many queries.)  You might need to change up your inputs so you know exactly what to update each player with.

This will also result in less looping and fewer queries.

```
@foreach($players as $player)    
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="player_ids[]" value="{{ $player->id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="game_id" value="{{ $game->id }}">
        <td>{{ $player->fn }} {{ $player->ln }}</td>
        <td><input type="number" value="0" name="goals[{{ $player->id }}]" placeholder="goals"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="0" name="assists[{{ $player->id }}]" placeholder="assists"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="0" name="tackles[{{ $player->id }}]" placeholder="tackles"></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach


$players_ids = $_POST['player_ids'];
foreach ($players_ids as $player_id) {
    $updates = \DB::table('stats')->where('id', $player_id)->update([
        'goals' => $_POST['goals'][$player_id],
        'assists' => $_POST['assists'][$player_id],
        'tackles' => $_POST['tackles'][$player_id]
    ]);
}
```

This is untested, but if you want it to be additive in your database and not overwrite past values, you might be able to do something like this...

```
$players_ids = $_POST['player_ids'];
foreach($players_ids as $player_id) {
    $updates = \DB::table('stats')->where('id', $player_id)->update([
        'goals' => $_POST['goals'][$player_id] . '+' . DB::raw('goals'),
        'assists' => $_POST['assists'][$player_id] . '+' . DB::raw('assists'),
        'tackles' => $_POST['tackles'][$player_id] . '+' . DB::raw('tackles')
    ]);
}
```

Generally a better route would be to not make them additive though, and then you'd just use `sum()` to figure out how many goals, tackles, and assists each player has.  Then you'd be able to do additional filtering on that like goals by date, goals by game, etc...

Comment: Thank you! The first solution does work, the second one I have not been able to get to function yet but I'll keep trying. I think what I'll end up doing is fetch and store the present values in the database inside variables and add those to the form values before submitting to the db. I know this probably isn't the best way to go about this I just don't see another way to do it. I have a Gamelog table as well that stores the same stats but on a game by game basis so they can easily be filtered by season/date range/game. A Gamelog is what feeds and updates the Stats table in this situation.